# JAR-RS Filter injection of a CDI Singleton that reference a @ConfigMapping object fails in Quarkus

Tags: jax-rs, config, cdi, quarkus

I try to use latest Qarkus configuration tool : @ConfigMapping so I defined a GreetingConfig object:

```java
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "org.acme.greeting")
public interface GreetingConfig {
    String prefix();
}
```

That config is injected in a CDI Singleton :

```java
@Singleton
public class GreetingService {

    @Inject GreetingConfig config;

    public String greet(String user) {
        return config.prefix().concat(" - Hello ").concat(user).concat(" !!");
    }
}
```

The singleton is injected in a JAX-RS Filter and in a JAX-RS Resource

```java
@Provider
public class GreetingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(GreetingFilter.class.getName());

    @Inject GreetingService service;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, service.greet("Quarkus"));
    }
}
```

```java
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @Inject GreetingService service;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello(@QueryParam("user") @DefaultValue("Quarkus") String user) {
        return service.greet(user);
    }
}
```

The application.properties file contains also :

```
org.acme.greeting.prefix=ACME Greetings
```

Application crash at startup :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:712)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:785)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:342)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl.run(StartupActionImpl.java:165)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:380)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.ensureStarted(QuarkusTestExtension.java:680)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.beforeAll(QuarkusTestExtension.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:192)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:136)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(ApplicationImpl.zig:225)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error injecting org.acme.GreetingService org.acme.api.filter.GreetingFilter.service
    at org.acme.api.filter.GreetingFilter_Bean.create(GreetingFilter_Bean.zig:148)
    at org.acme.api.filter.GreetingFilter_Bean.create(GreetingFilter_Bean.zig:171)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:96)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:29)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
    at org.acme.api.filter.GreetingFilter_Bean.get(GreetingFilter_Bean.zig:203)
    at org.acme.api.filter.GreetingFilter_Bean.get(GreetingFilter_Bean.zig:219)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:433)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:446)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl$1.get(ArcContainerImpl.java:269)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl$1.get(ArcContainerImpl.java:266)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.common.runtime.QuarkusConstructorInjector.construct(QuarkusConstructorInjector.java:39)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.injectedInstance(ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.java:1399)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.JaxrsInterceptorRegistryImpl$AbstractInterceptorFactory.createInterceptor(JaxrsInterceptorRegistryImpl.java:150)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.JaxrsInterceptorRegistryImpl$OnDemandInterceptorFactory.initialize(JaxrsInterceptorRegistryImpl.java:168)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.JaxrsInterceptorRegistryImpl$OnDemandInterceptorFactory.checkInitialize(JaxrsInterceptorRegistryImpl.java:183)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.JaxrsInterceptorRegistryImpl$OnDemandInterceptorFactory.getInterceptor(JaxrsInterceptorRegistryImpl.java:193)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.JaxrsInterceptorRegistryImpl$AbstractInterceptorFactory.postMatch(JaxrsInterceptorRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.JaxrsInterceptorRegistryImpl.postMatch(JaxrsInterceptorRegistryImpl.java:288)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ContainerRequestFilterRegistryImpl.postMatch(ContainerRequestFilterRegistryImpl.java:30)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ContainerRequestFilterRegistryImpl.postMatch(ContainerRequestFilterRegistryImpl.java:12)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.<init>(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:142)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.processMethod(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:381)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.register(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:308)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:259)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:227)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:192)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:175)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:87)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.registerResources(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:518)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.registration(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:475)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.startInternal(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.start(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:121)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.ResteasyStandaloneRecorder.staticInit(ResteasyStandaloneRecorder.java:37)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit-210558872.deploy_0(ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit-210558872.zig:897)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit-210558872.deploy(ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit-210558872.zig:40)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(ApplicationImpl.zig:205)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error injecting org.acme.config.GreetingConfig org.acme.GreetingService.config
    at org.acme.GreetingService_Bean.create(GreetingService_Bean.zig:199)
    at org.acme.GreetingService_Bean.create(GreetingService_Bean.zig:222)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:96)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:29)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
    at org.acme.GreetingService_Bean.get(GreetingService_Bean.zig:254)
    at org.acme.GreetingService_Bean.get(GreetingService_Bean.zig:270)
    at org.acme.api.filter.GreetingFilter_Bean.create(GreetingFilter_Bean.zig:131)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00027: Could not find a mapping for org.acme.config.GreetingConfig
    at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappings.getConfigMapping(ConfigMappings.java:73)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.getConfigMapping(SmallRyeConfig.java:423)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ConfigMappingCreator.create(ConfigMappingCreator.java:28)
    at org.acme.config.GreetingConfig_04302c935a6cb43e5f29ca4271833ab99b620b3b_Synthetic_Bean.create(GreetingConfig_04302c935a6cb43e5f29ca4271833ab99b620b3b_Synthetic_Bean.zig:128)
    at org.acme.config.GreetingConfig_04302c935a6cb43e5f29ca4271833ab99b620b3b_Synthetic_Bean.get(GreetingConfig_04302c935a6cb43e5f29ca4271833ab99b620b3b_Synthetic_Bean.zig:159)
    at org.acme.config.GreetingConfig_04302c935a6cb43e5f29ca4271833ab99b620b3b_Synthetic_Bean.get(GreetingConfig_04302c935a6cb43e5f29ca4271833ab99b620b3b_Synthetic_Bean.zig:182)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.CurrentInjectionPointProvider.get(CurrentInjectionPointProvider.java:52)
    at org.acme.GreetingService_Bean.create(GreetingService_Bean.zig:182)
    ... 93 more
```

Injection in the JAR-RS resource works whatever bean type the service is (@ApplicationScope nor @Singleton) but in the Filter, only @ApplicationScope bean can be injected avoiding the runtime exception...

Is it a bug or is it normal that we cannot inject a pseudo scope bean with config mapping in a JAX-RS @Provider (Filter or BodyWritter) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unfortunately, it's not a bug. It's a feature of jax-rs :-)**

1. I checked your configuration class, and it works with CDI beans
2. I checked your exact code at it failed with the same exception.
3. I dug into the documentation and found no explanation for injecting CDI to providers.
4. Also, many providers I have found weren't using CDIs at all.
5. Finally, I have learned that it is possible to Inject instance to the provider even if the bean is not yet there.

**A solution is to put your service into the Instance class.**

```
@Inject Instance<GreetingService> service;

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
   LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, service.get().greet("Quarkus"));
}
```

It delegates injection to the later phase (a kind of lazy injection during runtime).

I have found more info here
https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html

Comment: Hi, your solution works nice and the idea to use an Instance injection is definitively the good one I think !! Thanks, 
It is possible also to push the Instance injection on the config object in the service bean and to switch back to a classic injection in the provider.
Maybe it's a better design approach to let the bean aware of it's config injection and to deal with the Instance object itself, by the way idea is the same, avoid runtime problem whereas config object is not available at Provider instanciation time.

Comment: Yes. These solutions are so close that It's really hard to choose the one. I would probably stick with instance injection of the service class inside the provider, so the instance injection would be used only in the place it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Marek answer (thanks for the solution ;-)) there is also an option to use the Instance based injection on the config object in the Service Bean and to keep a classic injection in the Provider...

Maybe it's a better design approach to let the bean aware of it's config injection and to deal with the Instance object itself, by the way, initial idea is the same, avoiding runtime problem whereas config object is not available at Provider instanciation time by using an Instance.

```java
@Singleton
public class GreetingService {

    @Inject Instance<GreetingConfig> config;

    public String greet(String user) {
        return config.get().prefix().concat(" - Hello ").concat(user).concat(" !!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome Jerome. I have just found today this https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#caching-the-result-of-programmatic-lookup. When using Instance there is a risk of memory loss. Probably you should add @WithCaching annotation too!